# VoIP notifications in hybrid apps not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, voip, hybrid

Recently Apple changed its way of handling VoIP notifications. Now they force you to use CallKit in the same run loop in order not to throw your notification away. The trace I get is this one

```
Apps receving VoIP pushes must post an incoming call (via CallKit or IncomingCallNotifications) in the same run loop as  pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:[withCompletionHandler:] without delay.
```

When you get this warning three times, the system is "dropping your notifications on the floor".

The problem here is that I'm developing a hybrid VoIP app using the phonegap-plugin-push, and I'm afraid that the on notification event is not fast enough (or at least not the same run loop) for iOS.

Did anyone face this issue?

I've thought of changing to regular push notifications, but I can't find a way to make my app relaunch when it's killed and execute some code (launch CallKit, for example).

Edit: 
I'm trying this approach with push notifications and I already configured the background modes. I noticed that sending the "content-available" and some data, like "badge", or "alert" in the notification, the app is launched if it went to background recently. After 15 minutes in the background the push notification arrives but the app doesn't launch anymore

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Since iOS changed its policy about handling voip push notifications, it forces you to report a new incoming call when receiving the voip: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117939

This plugin does it: https://github.com/mattkhaw/cordova-plugin-callkit

It merges two plugins (WebsiteBeaver/CordovaCall and Hitman666/cordova-ios-voip-push). It worked for me. I just had to remove the receiveCall from the javascript and tweak a little bit the plugin.

The methods related to the voip notifications register are in the cordovaCall class, so it is pretty straightforward to work with.

Comment: i managed to integrate the plugin in my app as well. The problem that i have is that the notifications are not received when app is in background/killed. I am using simplepush.php script to test this https://github.com/Hitman666/cordova-ios-voip-push/blob/master/pushSendingScript/simplepush.php (modified version of it ).
How are you handling this?

Comment: anything on that one? It seems when all is in background all is OK now. My app crashes when app is killed thou

Comment: Just saw this! So sorry I didn't answer. Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Our app uses CallKit and push notifications, and it launches when a push notification arrives for a new incoming call.  It has to be configured in the project build and run once to register with iOS for this, though.

Comment: Does your app work for iOS 13 as well. I edit my post to add this right away!

Comment: @Borja, yes, iOS 13.  By the way, we found helpful info with Console on the Mac attached to the iPhone under test.  Specifically, there were sometimes log entries from callservicesd saying, in effect, "not going to launch <our app> because …"

Comment: when you say "it has to be configured in the project build"... where do I have to configure it? Could you give me any hint?

Comment: I already configured the background modes if that's what you meant. I noticed that sending the "content-available" and some data, like "badge", or "alert" in the notification, the app is launched if it went to background recently. After 15 minutes in the background the push notification arrives but the app doesn't launch anymore.

Comment: @Borja, yes, the background mode is what I meant.  In practice, the VoIP push notification arrives at the phone, CallKit launches our app and delivers the notification, and we have about 5 seconds to report to CallKit the UUID we assigned.  That report brings up the CK call controller.  If we exceed that time, then the warning you described is issued.  I hope that time frame helps.